# Automate spacewalk server installation

Tags: spacewalk

I'm trying to automate spacewalk server deployment. I stuck at creating first user. Is there any way do it non-interactively, via commandline or api? RPC seems to be unavailable at this stage so I can't use spacecmd.

The goal is automatically create development/testing environments for developing of piece of software which integrates with spacewalk. Of course I can manually create OS image the clone it and customize, but I'd like have whole process as code.

Comment: have you considered ansible?

Comment: Sure. I'm working on vagrant currently. I can provision it with Ansible. Do you have any experiences?